# cp and mkdir :No such file or directory

Tags: wordpress

When I try to use this command:
   $ mkdir /tmp/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade

It comes up with a message:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/tmp/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade': No such file or directory
```

Actually before I typed `chmod 660 /tmp/wordpress/ .htaccess`

Then I typed   `$ cp /tmp/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php`

Then comes up with `cp: failed to access '/tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php': Permisson denied`

Please someone help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the terminal output instead of a photo. Also explain why you're creating a directory in `/tmp`.  You might find `mkdir -p ` will work but I don't think that's addressing the real problem.

Comment: Does the `/tmp/wordpress/` exist? Can you post the contents of said folder?

Comment: Can you post all your steps?

Comment: post the output of `ls -la /tmp/wordpress/wp-config*`

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/wordpress/wp-content/upgrade
```

will create all the missing sub directories.

Reason for your error: either `/tmp/` or `/tmp/wordpress/` does not exist. Also make sure when creating directories outside your `/home/` that you own them as that user; otherwise you will also need `sudo` in front of the commands.

Personal note: I would use a location in `/home/$USER/` for updates for wordpress.

Comment: I get it now but how do I resolve this.

Comment: With the `-p` parameter I added in my example. You are missing that one in yours.

Comment: It really works but what about the $ cp /tmp/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php

Comment: That depends on what you did before the cp. Where did that file come from? Cuz you made a directory but that will not create a file.

Comment: Actually before I typed chmod 660 /tmp/wordpress/ .htaccess

Then I typed  $ cp /tmp/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php

Then comes up with cp: failed to access '/tmp/wordpress/wp-config.php': Permisson denied